# Dequant layer in tflite model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, quantization, tflite, quantization-aware-training

I am running the training example for Quantization aware training as is in Google Colab.
You can find the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example).

My exact code can be found [here](https://github.com/LeNovice/PSW/blob/main/Copy_of_training_example.ipynb). I expected that all the layers in the output frozen model (.tflite) would be quantized (integer, int8 precisely)

However, I noticed a dequantize node present in the layers.

[image]

I am not sure what leads to this dequant node. This is not desirable and I would like to remove it, preferable with network surgery.